# how to use log4cxx under the Red Hat 7

Tags: c++, linux, log4cxx

I am trying to use log4cxx in my c++ project under the system Red Hat 7.

So I download it with this command: yum install log4cxx.x86_64

After that, I type this command: rpm -ql log4cxx and get this message:

- /usr/lib64/liblog4cxx.so.10
- /usr/lib64/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0
- /usr/share/doc/log4cxx-0.10.0
- /usr/share/doc/log4cxx-0.10.0/KEYS
- /usr/share/doc/log4cxx-0.10.0/LICENSE
- /usr/share/doc/log4cxx-0.10.0/NOTICE

Now I dont know how to use the log4cxx in my project. Where is the head files? Where is the lib files?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
yum search log4cxx
```

you will get:

```
....
log4cxx.i686 : A port to C++ of the Log4j project
log4cxx.x86_64 : A port to C++ of the Log4j project
log4cxx-devel.i686 : Header files for Log4xcc - a port to C++ of the Log4j project
log4cxx-devel.x86_64 : Header files for Log4xcc - a port to C++ of the Log4j project
```

Just do `yum install log4cxx-devel` too

Comment: thx. But when I search log4cxx, I can only get log4cxx.i686 and log4cxx.x86_64. So I cant download the log4cxx-devel because it cant be found. So my yum.repos.d miss something??

Comment: I've just tried again with a centos7, fresh install I have handy: both runtime and devel files are found from the online standard repositories.

Comment: ah with RedHat you need to register the server in order to have access to all the official repositories! - by default only the basic subset is available - I think they are called subscription repositories, or something similar.